# Why are answers with minimal information getting up voted?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality, votes

[Asian movie about a guy recording sounds and sending them to his girlfriend](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/321/asian-movie-about-a-guy-recording-sounds-and-sending-them-to-his-girlfriend)

Here is my example. The question is decent but the answer is basically it's called ___ and it's from this country. Yet 7 people considered that a response that needed more points. I think it basically validates and does nothing to discourage people that leave the minimum information.

Comment: No real answer to that - but I can understand your surprise.  Its not ideal to provide that little information, but from our 850 users there are 7 that are rewarding someone's work in identifying the movie.  The mods do tend to ask people to expand answers like this, but we can't force people.

Comment: Yes I received 3 great answers. I didn't realize this question was posted during the private beta. I was simply looking over past questions and answers and thought that it was strange but a good example of points being added for little reason.

Comment: I think it can be hard to provide a very detailed answer to a "Identify this movie" question, without just quoting IMDB. As the asker to an identify question, once the movie is sufficiently identified by title, and possibly by year, country, etc (if the title is ambiguous), I would feel the question is sufficiently answered, even if the answer is only a few words.

Comment: That maybe but I feel there is a difference of effort if someone responds simply with "This is your movie. Here is the IMDB/Wiki" versus " Here is the movie. The IMDB/Wiki page gives the exact same description as you did." Or if a scene from the movie could be found and posted that helps person who asked to be sure they have the correct answer.

Comment: Here is a question with a near perfect example actually. http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1351/movie-about-a-couple-moving-into-a-neighborhood-and-are-acually-salespeople

Comment: @KevinHowell: In that example, I think the lower-voted answer is actually better, because (aside from the link in the accepted answer) it actually provides _more_ identifying information. If "The Jonses" had been remade, the plot summary would not be sufficient to identify which one the question was about.

Comment: I don't understand. The first answer gives a possible name for the movie and a plot summary to help the questioner compare. The second answer Gives the name and year it came out plus two actor but otherwise gives no details on this site as to why this is the answer to the question. The question doesn't list a year or any of the actors. Even though they both have the right answer it seems one person answered with enough detail that the questioner didn't need to go to another site than this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact of the matter is, the up/down vote options are there and **no one is stopping anyone from using them**.  The only thing that can be done is for the mods to comment on it (I don't personally like editing it, even though we can as it is too heavy of a modification) and for others to *downvote*.  If people want to *upvote* it enough and there are *no flags* against the answer, there is **no valid reason** to delete/edit it.

It only further shows that this site is *community* driven.  If the community rewards this, then people won't learn.  If the community flags and downvotes, it shows that it is unacceptable and people will learn that way.  Sure downvoting an answer comes at a cost of a *whopping -1* rep, it is a further consequence for the answerer, as well as this rep lost by downvoting is *easily* made up by **suggesting an edit** and having it approved (it results in a +1 gain)

Also, as my fellow mods have pointed out, the question and answer were both from when the site was merely a week old, therefore upvotes abound to encourage people to post more Q&A on the site.

Comment: I received 3 great answers here. I voted yours as the answer because I think it addressed the overall issue of how to handle positive rating for minimal answers the best.

Comment: Accepted edits earn +2 rep, not +1. Or maybe you meant DV + edit = +1 net gain?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, the answer you highlight was posted on December 8 - only a few days into the beta.  People were a little more 'upvote happy' then than they are now.  If you look back, in the first few days of the site, some questions got voted up far more than they really deserved.

Often the moderators will prompt someone to add to an answer like this, but we can't force people. An answer like this is better than no answer at all, so we won't delete it.

If you think an answer is undeserving of its score - it is up to the community to downvote it.

Comment: I see DFork42 got there first.

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree. A few thinsg to keep in mind though is that:

1. This question was posted during the private beta, meaning people were a lot more candid with their votes
2. It's also the accepted answer
3. No one has downvoted it

There is a prod from @Tylershads for more info, but the user hasn't been on since January.  Another person, knowledgable about this answer, could edit the answer with more info.

I would downvote it, but alas I was one of those that voted too candidly in the private beta.

Comment: Hey no problem it's always nice to promote but I just couldn't understand at first why it was so popular. Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm generally a major promoter of long, detailed answers (browse through my profile on a few sites if you have doubts), and I do agree that it's all too common here to have insufficient answers that are highly upvoted, but you didn't pick a good example. This is a movie identification question, and finding the name of the movie is the hard part. It's better if the answer explains how the proposed movie fits the description, but the answer is ok without it. It's not like, say, a question about a plot point where a thorough explanation is a must.

Comment: I did choose a bad example it seems. However I've seen numerous post from moderators that ask a person to not just refer to another site or source of information. Plus it's easy enough to post a simple plot summary or even point out why the movie in an answer is the correct one that answers the question. It also lets other that read the question know why this answer was the correct or best answer.